# Accessing data in table pointed to by foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following query in MySQL:

```
select first_name, idStudent2
from `Student` join `Friend`
on `Student`.`idStudent` = `Friend`.`idStudent1`;
```

it gives the result

```
Camille   1
Emily     5
Bob       6
Bob       7
...
```

The result is showing the student name, and then the student-ID of a friend of that student.

The table named `Student` is a table of all the students in a (school) database. `Friend` is a unary Many-to-Many relationship on student.

Instead of the result showing the student-ID in the second column, I would like it to show the student name that corresponds to that ID.

`idStudent1` and `idStudent2` are foreign key pointing to the primary key of the `Student` table. So basically, I want a means of accessing the information in the table row that the foreign key `idStudent2` points to.

The desired result would look something like this:

```
Camille    Trevor
Emily      Bob
Bob        James
Bob        Katrina
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is join the `Student` table twice. One time for `Friend.idStudent1` and one time for `Friend.idStudent2`

```
select s1.first_name, s2.first_name
from Friend   f 
join Student s1 on s1.idStudent = f.idStudent1
join Student s2 on s2.idStudent = f.idStudent2;
```

As you are joining the same table twice you need to use aliases to distinguish them. Here I've used `s1` and `s2` for the `Student` tables and `f` for the `Friend` table. Aliases also helps to keep the query short and tidy.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!